# VBA Concatenate via If Statement Error

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I'm working with a phone company that is allowing me to send SMS messages via an e-mail routing system.  So, I'll email the message to their server and it will be sent via sms to the end number. The thing is, I need to convert hundreds of phone numbers of various formats into an e-mail address using the to-from@... format (to/from including 1 + area code).

I wrote a formula that works great: =IF(LEN(a1)=5,CONCATENATE("1813",a1,"00","-1813xxxxxxx@sms.xx.com"),IF(LEN(a1)=6,CONCATENATE("1813",a1,"0","-1813xxxxxxx@sms.xx.com"),IF(LEN(a1)=10,CONCATENATE("1",a1,"-1813xxxxxxx@sms.xx.com"),(IF(LEN(a1)=7,CONCATENATE("1813",a1,"-1813xxxxxxx@sms.xx.com"),a1)))))

It adds the required text, but I'd like to make this into a VBA.

I'm new to VBA (forgive me if this is a rookie mistake), but this is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SMSemail()

Dim phone1 As String
Dim smsaddy As String

Dim x As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To lastrow

phone1 = Cells(x, 4).Value

If phone1.Value = 7 Then smsaddy = "1813" & phone1 & "-18136896527@xx.com"

Cells(x, 5).Value = smsaddy

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Right now I'm getting a compile error but I've tweaked it a few times and sometimes its a "variable undefined" on the lastrow line...  I don't understand it though since it seems like I'm defining everything up above; I'm lost and hoping you can help!  Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

- You need to declare the `lastrow` variable.
- with a multi-line If statement, you need a new line after the `then`
- `phone1`is a string, so you cant use `phone1.value`, just use `phone1` since you've already assigned the value to that variable.

The code works fine when written like this

```
Option Explicit
Sub SMSemail()

Dim phone1 As String
Dim smsaddy As String
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim x As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To lastrow

phone1 = Cells(x, 4).Value

If phone1 = 7 Then

    smsaddy = "1813" & phone1 & "-18136896527@xx.com"

    Cells(x, 5).Value = smsaddy

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I had to add a If Len(phone1) = 7 Then but that did the trick!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Set smsaddy to "" at the beginning, or in an `else`. Whenever phone1.value is not 7, smaddy is not currently initialized.

Move `smsaddy = "1813" & phone1 & "-18136896527@xx.com"` to the following line.